# How do I access property within an object within an array?

Tags: magento-1.9, soap

I'm using the [following example](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/customer/customer.list.html) from Magento api to check for a specific customer:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://localhost/magento/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');

$session = $client->login('fakeuser', 'fakepass');

$complexFilter = array(
    'complex_filter' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'email',
            'value' => array('key' => 'in', 'value' => 'thecustomer@imlookingfor.com')
        )
    )
);
$result = $client->customerCustomerList($session, $complexFilter);

if (empty($result)) {
    echo "no customer found";
} else {
    var_dump($result);
    // echo $result[0]->stdClass->fistname; // code in question
}
```

here's the response I'm getting

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (10) {
    ["customer_id"]=>
    int(52)
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(19) "2014-09-14 03:08:27"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "2014-09-14 03:08:28"
    ["store_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["website_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["created_in"]=>
    string(18) "Default Store View"
    ["email"]=>
    string(21) "thecustomer@imlookingfor.com"
    ["firstname"]=>
    string(6) "John"
    ["lastname"]=>
    string(10) "Doe"
    ["group_id"]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

what I'm trying to do is echo out the customer's first name. I tried this:

```
echo $result[0]->stdClass->fistname;
```

but I'm getting these errors.

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$stdClass in /Users/sergey/Desktop/andagain/control-panel/check-if-customer-exists.php on line 24

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/sergey/Desktop/andagain/control-panel/check-if-customer-exists.php on line 24
```

What am I missing?

Comment: give me 10 min I will working on that

Comment: yes I found Solution

Comment: I need more reputation to vote. But I will once I get there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing the property in wrong manner so it will give you error. try below one.

When you try to access the data using SOAP then

```
<?php  
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
echo "<pre>";
/* not Mage::run(); */
Mage::app();
try
{   

    $proxy = new SoapClient('http://localhost:81/magento/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'); // TODO : change url
    $sessionId = $proxy->login('admin', '123456'); // TODO : change login and pwd if necessary

    $result = $proxy->customerCustomerList($sessionId);
    print_r($result[0]);
    print_r($result[0]->firstname);

}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    print_r($e);
    echo $e->getMessage();      
}
?>
```

Let me know If any comments.

Comment: I know Buddy I have try first then I will give you proper solution.